# How to include multiple categories in junit4?

Tags: junit, junit4

I want to include multiple categories for a junit runner.

**Java Code**

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(IMAP.class , POP.class)
@SuiteClasses({MailTestSuites.class})
public class TestSuiteRunner{

}
```

I want to run my test suite for these two categories only. I have categories for mail suite like "IMAP,POP , SMTP , POP3". Now , I want to run only "IMAP , POP" category suites only. 
How can I run with junit?

Answer (score 1):

Up to version JUnit 4.11, `@IncludeCategory` and `@ExcludeCategory` only support one value. However, starting with the upcoming release 4.12, it will be allowed to pass multiple values.

According to the [documentation in the source code](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.java#L71), you can then write:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory({IMAP.class, POP.class})
@SuiteClasses({MailTestSuites.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you couldn't define multiple values of `@IncludeCategory` in one `Categories`.

I recommend you use multiple `Categories` to run your test cases. (Separate IMAP and POP test cases)

```
//IMAP tests
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(IMAP.class)
@SuiteClasses({MailTestSuites1.class})
public class TestSuiteRunner1{}

//POP tests
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(POP.class)
@SuiteClasses({MailTestSuites2.class})
public class TestSuiteRunner2{}

//Merge into one Test
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestSuiteRunner1.class, 
    TestSuiteRunner2.class})
public class AllTests {}
```

Comment: How can I run with multiple categories?